# Cocos Studio: Cocos Framework is not installed error

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocostudio

I installed Cocos Studio v2.3.3 to C:\Cocos using the link to a non-framework included package on the cocos2d-x.org site. I then unpacked cocos2d-x v3.9 using the zip file provided into the C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.9 - but Cocos Studio doesn't recognize that the Cocos2d-x framework is installed.

When I look in the Platform section of the Preferences menu item under the Edit menu, it show this:
[image: Platform section of the Preferences menu item showing that Cocos Framework is not installed]

And as expected, when I try to modify an already created project options, I see this:
[image: Project options dialog showing that no engine is installed]

I've tried all the suggestions posted in the Cocos2d-x forums, including but not limited to editing the Frameworks\FrameworksVersionList.xml to include the entry for cocos2d-x-3.9 (it was already there), editing the cocos2d.ini file in tools\console\bin, removing various combinations and then all cocos environment variables and quite a few others. None of the solutions either by themselves or in combination with one another worked.

Has anyone gotten Cocos Studio to work with a separate installation of Cocos2d-x framework?

Answer (score 0):

Details of the solution with various things I tried are listed in this blog post: http://vijay.tech/talks/solved-cocos-studio-cocos-framework-is-not-installed-error/ Note that the post has a registry edit script (.REG file) attached for convenience.

But the essential steps are listed here:

1. Download and install [Cocos for Windows V2.3.3](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/filedown/CocosForWin-v2.3.3.exe) (the one without framework) to C:\Cocos
2. Download and unzip [cocos2d-x-3.9.zip](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/filedown/cocos2d-x-3.9.zip) to C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.9
3. Manually create the following registry entries on Windows (64 bit):

   1. **`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\CocosFramework\InstallDir`** as a REG_SZ and set it to **`C:\Cocos`**
   2. **`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\CocosFramework\3.9\EngineVersion`** as a REG_SZ and set it to **`cocos2d-x-3.9`**
   3. **`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\CocosFramework\3.9\Path`** as a REG_SZ and set it to **`C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.9`**
4. Create a file named **`version`** with the contents **`cocos2d-x-3.9`** in **`C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.9`**
5. If you also want to do Android development, then Android SDK, Android NDK, Ant and JDK paths should be set in the Platform section of the Edit/Preferences menu item, else skip this step.